# Downloading Android Kernel for iptables

Tags: android, git, repository

I am trying to download the kernel sources of android for emulator so that I can run iptables nat commands and play around.

I got the android 4.1 sources and compiled them. Now I am trying to download the kernel using:
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/kernel/common.git kernel

It returns the following error:

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/mydir/WORKING_DIRECTORY/kernel/.git/
android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)

Any idea?

I had downloaded the repo script to download the android sources, so then I tried adding

in manifest.xml under .repo and then I did:

repo sync

However, this again resulted in the same error as above.

Please help

Comment: please help. I need to download android kernel. Isn't there any other way than git or repo -init ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading from :

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git

Worked!